# Why wget doesn't read HTTP_PROXY in uppercase format?

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, http, sles

I know in unix/linux the enviroment variables are uppercase, like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH ; HOME ; $USER` and so on. Today playing with wget I saw this commands just uses lowercase enviroment variables:

```
env | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=http://10.0.0.120:8080
wget -q http://google.it
echo $?
0
unset http_proxy
export HTTP_PROXY=http://10.0.0.120:8080
wget -q http://google.it
echo $?
1
```

Why wget doesn't read `HTTP_PROXY` in uppercase format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a guess, but project timelines would suggest that it's for backwards compatibility with Lynx, which predates curl by a few years (and which uses lower-case proxy variables).

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: Unfortunately, different programs use different `env` variables.

Long answer, from (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/proxy_settings#Environment_variables):

> Some programs (like wget) use environment variables of the form "protocol_proxy" to determine the proxy for a given protocol. (...) Some programs look for the all caps version of the environment variables.

In the past, I've made a simple script that sets both versions (all caps and "regular" versions to toggle them on and off easily, and it seems that that is a common way of doing things if it must be done via `env` variables.

Answer (score 1):

Unix is case sensitive. Which means that $http_proxy and $HTTP_PROXY are two different variables.

Look at this:

```
user@foo[~]+ xx=2
user@foo[~]+ echo $xx
2
user@foo[~]+ echo $XX

user@foo[~]+
```

Comment: yes i know, the @Gerald Combs answers, is ok